# How to drop pandas consecutive column by column name simultaneously?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
Id   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4 ....  Column112  Column113 ... Column143
1         67       89       86       43              56         72            67
```

The Output I expected,

```
Id   Column1  Column113 ... Column143
1         67         72            67
```

What I did

```
df.drop(['Column2', 'Column3', ... ,'Column112'], axis = 1)
```

But this is not efficient, how to do this effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.drop(df.loc[:, 'Column2':'Column112'].columns, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you do that by column name?

Answer (score 1):

You can otherwise use .loc to get the columns from column names as follows:

```
df=df.loc[:,['Id', 'Column1',  'Column113', ..., 'Column143']
```